# Common nodes between max and min heaps with same key value?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, data-structures, heapsort

I mean to say that what can be maximum possibility the number of positions in which the key values remains same for max and min heaps where both heaps have key values 1 to n?

In simplest way,
A binary max heap and a binary min heap each with the key values 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 in such a way that the number
of positions in which the key values in the two heaps are identical is as many as possible. How many positions are
they identical at, in this case?

Comment: Its hard to understand. Can you ask in simpler terms?

Answer (score -1):

Asymptotically, there can be at least n/3 values which have the same position.
Let n=2<sup>k</sup>-1, so we have 2<sup>k-1</sup> elements on the last level and 2<sup>k-2</sup> elements on the pre-last level.

Let us put the elements in the min-heap in array order: 1 at the top, 2 and 3 at the second level, 4-7 on the third level, and so on.
Now, look at elements n/3 to 2n/3 (with a +-1 at the borders, but that's irrelevant for asymptotic behavior). They occupy the end (2/3) of pre-last level and the start (1/3) of last level.
None of the elements in this set is a descendant of another element from the set,
so it fits both a min-heap and a max-heap.
What's more, there is room for 1/3 values at the top of this set and 1/3 values at the bottom of it.

So, to make a max-heap with this set on the same positions, we can swap the top and bottom thirds, and then arrange the elements there according to the max-heap rules.
For example, they can be just put in descending array order.

An example for n=15 (hexadecimal numbers):

```
    min-heap                 max-heap
        1                        F       
    2       3                E       D   
  4   5   6   7            C   B   6   7 
 8 9 A B C D E F          8 9 A 5 4 3 2 1
```

As you can see, the elements 6, 7, 8, 9, and A have the same positions in both heaps.
The 1-5 part is moved to the bottom, and their order at the bottom can be arbitrary.
The B-F part is moved to the top and rearranged into F-B to make a max-heap.

Comment: Actually, another straightforward example can be constructed when n = 3 * (2^k - 1). Then the middle third occupies exactly one level.

Comment: Consider the min-heap `[1,3,2,4]` and the max-heap `[4,3,2,1]`. In that case, n/2 items have the same position. I wonder if it's possible to construct such an arrangement for larger heaps.

Comment: @JimMischel I doubt the constant can get to 1/2 in asymptotic, but didn't prove that, and in fact don't know if we can do better than 1/3. We need our set to not have any one element being a descendant of any other, so the best case looks more or less like a level of the tree, maybe skewed. Furthermore, there should be enough space, either at top and bottom of our set, or independent ("at the side") of our set, to put all elements which don't belong to the set. The constant 1/2 would mean we use the very last level of the tree, which does not have space at the bottom to put other elements.